# JS function unexpected result?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out this code...

```
function addTen(x) {
  return x + 10;
}

function divideByThree(y) {
  return y / 3;
}

var result = addTen(2);
console.log(divideByThree(result));
```

How i took it is like that. result should be 20 because it says (2) so 10 x 2 = 20 then divide it by 3 and that's 6,something.
Well,it actually equals 4,why is that? Can anyone explain please?

Comment: (2 + 10) / 3 = 20 ?

Comment: The first function is called *add* ten, not multiply ten.

Answer (score 0):

`addTen` does not multiply by 2, it adds 10 to 2:

`10 + 2 = 12`

Then divided by 3: `12 / 3 = 4`

Comment: so basically in the function addTen adds ten to the x which on our case happens to be 2. I got it thanks sir.

Comment: Please accept my answer if that's what you were looking for